# Market Billing Service could not be bound in android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

when i can run my app bill program in my emulator its show the Market Billing Service could not be bound.

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i(TAG, "Service starting with onCreate");

        try {
            boolean bindResult = bindService(new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.MarketBillingService.BIND"), this, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
            if(bindResult){
                Log.i(TAG,"Market Billing Service Successfully Bound");
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG,"Market Billing Service could not be bound.");
                //TODO stop user continuing
            }
        } catch (SecurityException e){
            Log.e(TAG,"Market Billing Service could not be bound. SecurityException: "+e);
            //TODO stop user continuing
        }
    }
```

it means **bindService** not return true value.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: maybe you need google play installed which is not possible in emulators. Try with a device.

Comment: i have success fully connect with google play after click on button but its not showing price and card number now it shows default value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Market billing wont be supported in emulator.try it in your device

Answer (score 1):

It can not be tested on the emulator (since emulator doesn't have Android Market.). [Testing In-app Billing](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html) section of official site says

> You cannot use the emulator to test in-app billing; you must install your application on a device to test in-app billing.

Comment: hi Praful,
i have success fully connect with google play after click on button but its not showing price and card number properly.